# How to inject a custom BeanFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

For a custom `Scope` (I cannot post here because of legal reasons) I need a custom `BeanFactory` that overrides the `getBean(Class requiredType)` method, like:

```
public class MyBeanFactory implements BeanFactory {

    @Override
    public <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException {
        if(MyScope.someSetting) {
            return useBeanA();
        } else {
            return useBeanB();
        }
    }
}
```

This `BeanFactory` must be used in my whole spring container for getting beans (by type). How can I inject it in the `ApplicationContext` (or do I need a custom `ApplicationContext`)?

I cannot use a `FactoryBean`, because the logic is not special to one (or a few) bean(s). I cannot use a `InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor` because its `postProcessBeforeInstantiation()` method is called only onced.

Comment: Isn't this something that should be handled only by the scope of the bean? So if your problem really is applying a scope to all beans instead of the normal singleton scope, than maybe it would be a better idea to have a look at how you achieve this. What kind of application context are you using or is it required to be a generic solution?

Comment: My custom scope is applied only to some beans, not all. That's why I need some modification of the instantiation / selection logic. I am using the `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContex`

Comment: But can't your custom scope just do what you are currently trying to achieve in `MyBeanFactory.getBean` in its method own `MyCustomScope.get(String, ObjectFactory<?>)`?

Comment: Thanks. I now see, what you mean. I will try it ...

Comment: Currently I just call `objectFactory.getObject()` and unfortunately this is the only method of `ObjectFactory`. I may cast it to `BeanFactory` to get other beans, but I am not sure, if this is a good idea?

Comment: How about making you scope `ApplicationContextAware`?

Comment: I tried that as I tried to autowire the `ApplicationContext`. Both does not work. The `ApplicationContext` gets not injected.

Comment: I was wrong. It gets injected, but too late.

Comment: I injected a `BeanFactory` by the constructor of the `Scope`. That works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by 'spacetrucker' (see the comments to the question), I solved the problem quite different. I added my bean instantiation / selection logic to my custom `Scope` and injected a `BeanFactory` by the constructor to this `Scope`.